# ODI Flat File not getting detected

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-data-integrator

I am an ODI newbie, currently working on simple ODI POCs. I am trying to extract data from a flat file (.txt) and insert it into an Oracle table as per this tutorial http://www.odigurus.com/2012/02/delimiter-flat-file-rdbms-table-loading.html. However, no matter how I try, ODI refuses to detect the file. I have placed the file on the E:. I have tried placing it on C:\ and in folders. Still it doesn't seem to work. I get the message that the directory specified in your schema does not exist and then a message that file could not be found.

Can anyone kindly help me out with this. Please let me know if more information is required.

Regards,
Sparky

Answer (score 1):

The .TXT file has to be placed on the server where odi is installed and not on the local drive. The folder should have read privileges for odi to pick up.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's related to what you entered as "Directory (Schema)" and "Directory (Work Schema)" in your Physical Schema. Check that the path you put there is correct.

Also make sure you used slashes (**/**) instead of backslashes (**\**).

Kind Regards,

JeromeFr

Comment: Hi JeromeFr, I assure you the Schema definitions in Topology are correct. Refer to the image here of my Physical Schema definition http://snag.gy/U5Rg3.jpg

Answer (score 0):

If still your issue is not solved and for any other facing the same issue then you can try this:
Probably you missed setting the reverse context for the Model.
What you can do is just double click on your Model and set the context to what you have created or to **Global** (as in my case) if you are running it in default global context. See the image below (In your case I am sure it will be **Undefined**):
[image: setting up the context]

Hope that should solve your issue. All the best!